# What do you call this accent circle's graphic style?

Tags: vector, svg, icon, illustration, style-identification

[image]

I'm looking at the accent circles behind the gentleman's portrait. It seems like this has been a common graphic style for a while. Primarily used in loader animations, but I've also seen flat graphics of straight lines with the breaks/sliced vectors.

I would say it's properties are "broken path, offset, circle, simple, stroked, rounded, vector"

I want to find similar stuff, but I'm not sure what this style is called!

This is another example of the flat design, line segment style I'm referring to: https://pngtree.com/freepng/abstract-geometric-color-concentric-circle-text-box_5236753.html

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I'd just say "decorative concentric rings". Not everything has a name.

Comment: @Zach Saucier YES!! An image search for "concentric vectors" results in the closest thing. Thanks! Still not sure how to classify the flat line style composed of broken paths, and short strokes among longer ones. I see it used often for shading in flat illustrations like this https://st3.depositphotos.com/7840366/12923/v/600/depositphotos_129232476-stock-illustration-airport-concept-illustration-line-flat.jpg

Comment: @djangodev Searching along the lines of "stroke dash" can probably help you with that aspect

Comment: I think merely searching for "concentric circle designs" would be your best bet. Overall it's *not* really a "style" it's a common design element with or without broken paths. It's fairly ubiquitous.